# windows API shellexecute is failing to execute batch file

Tags: winapi

I am trying to execute a batch file using shellexecute, but its not getting executed.
Below is the way I am using the API:

```
temp += "cmd.exe /C c:\\AutoTest\\Target1_CmdList.bat ";
    HINSTANCE hReturnCode=ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), NULL,temp.c_str(), "C:\\Autotest", SW_HIDE);
```

Can anyone tell me is this the right way?
I searched the posts that mentioned about the same and made the changes accordingly.

Thanks

Comment: As an aside, it seems that in comments you know that you have passed the file name in the wrong parameter. And yet you still posted that code. This is a common mistake. You get stuck. You try a bunch of stuff at random. Your code gets worse and worse. Then you ask the question posting the last code you have, the code that has all your erroneous trial and error experiments in. Please take more care. Post the best code you have.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `NULL` for the `lpFile` argument. That argument cannot be omitted and must specify the name of the file which you wish to perform the action on.

Presumably you meant to write:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), temp.c_str(), NULL, "C:\\Autotest", SW_HIDE);
```

There is little point in passing `cmd.exe` to `ShellExecute`. The shell knows what to do with a `.bat` file. Pass the `.bat` file directly.

It would be better to use `ShellExecuteEx` since it is capable of proper error reporting, unlike `ShellExecute`. Check for errors as described at MSDN. Check the return value of `ShellExecuteEx`, and if it is false then call `GetLastError` to obtain an error code.

What is more, it seems incongruous to use the `_T()` macro some times and not others. I suggest that you stop using the `_T()` macro and decide whether to target ANSI or Unicode.

Comment: I tried that way as well, still it is failing.Its just opening the folder c:\Autotest the path I have given as fourth parameter.

Comment: Then there is an error somewhere else. We just answer the questions that you ask. Or do you think that the code in your question is correct? That it is fine to omit `lpFile`. Perhaps I misunderstand you.

Comment: I tried with below as: ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), temp.c_str(), NULL, "C:\\Autotest", SW_HIDE); Since it dint work I tried by placing the temp value as fourth parameter the one I have asked in question. Both are not working. My problem is I want to execute the batch file using shellexecute, the same is working fine with createprocess, but the requirement is to use shellexecute API

Comment: Do remember that I have no idea what is in `temp`, or indeed your .bat. I don't know how your program fails. And you've not done any error checking. It's time for you to stop hoping for an instant fix and put some graft in to debug your program. Start by making all the changes I recommend.

Comment: @Sneha: Unrelated to your problem, but who would ever require you to use a broken API (`ShellExecute`), when a fixed one exists (`ShellExecuteEx`)?